# Eager fetching blobs in Ebean under certain cases

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

Is there a way to make ebean eagerly fetch the blobs under certain cases using the ebean Query API? I know that discarding the `@Lob` annotation will make ebean fetch the blobs but this will fetch the blobs under all cases which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

After looking a bit at the Javadoc of the Ebean Query API. I found out how to do that using:

```
query.select("*");
```

Will make ebean fetch all columns of the table including blobs. Alternatively if you want to just fetch the blob you could use:

```
query.select("blobPropertyName");
```